# Unexpected function expression - ESLint error when using MUI Snackbar Component customized with Alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, eslint, snackbar

I want to create a customized MUI [Snackbar](https://mui.com/components/snackbars/) using MUI Alert by following the example in the official Documentation but ESlint is showing me this error:

```
error  Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback
error  Prop spreading is forbidden     react/jsx-props-no-spreading
```

in this part of the code:

```
const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});
```

I used `npx eslint . --fix` to fix the issue but now I am getting:

```
error  Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
error  Prop spreading is forbidden                   react/jsx-props-no-spreading
```

Here is My full [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/9uooc?file=/demo.js):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

export default function CustomizedSnackbars() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open success snackbar
      </Button>
      <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
          This is a success message!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are just eslint (code formatting rules) see the fixes:
https://codesandbox.io/s/customizedsnackbars-material-demo-forked-uu04g?file=/demo.js

Comment: @guiwme5 I know it is Eslint fixes, and I don't want to disable the rule,  I am looking for an alternative solution that works with Eslint rules as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are your eslint error

```js
error  Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback
error  Prop spreading is forbidden     react/jsx-props-no-spreading
error  Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
```

prefer-arrow-callback: use this => in the forward

```js
const Alert = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});
```

react/display-name

```js
const Alert = () => {
  .... 
}
Alert.displayName = "Alert";
```

react/jsx-props-no-spreading

if you don't want disable it you will have to list all the MuiAlert props and pass it through

```js
const Alert = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {
    action,
    children,
    classes,
    closeText,
    color,
    icon,
    iconMapping ,
    onClose,
    event,
    role,
    severity,
    sx,
    variant = "filled,
  } = props;
  return <MuiAlert ref={ref} elevation={6} variant={variant} action={action} ... />;
});
```